# Is '-9' a flag to kill command?

Tags: utilities, kill, options

**What does `-9` do?**

It does not show up in the syntax:

```
$ kill
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
$
```

Comment: `-9` is an instance of `-sigspec`, it's equivalent to `-s 9` or `-n 9` or `-s KILL` or `-KILL`.

Answer (score 23):

`-9` is the signal number (in this case `SIGKILL`), so `kill -9` sends a `SIGKILL` to the process in question.

This signal causes the process to terminate immediately (unless it's waiting in a kernel function). The signal can neither be ignored nor can the receiving process perform any clean up action after receiving the signal (i.e. a signal handler for `SIGKILL` is not called). See also the [Wikipedia article on SIGKILL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL).

From the man page of my `kill` command (Linux):

```
   The  default  signal  for  kill is TERM. Use -l or -L to list available
   signals.  Particularly useful signals include  HUP,  INT,  KILL,  STOP,
   CONT,  and  0.   Alternate  signals  may be specified in three ways: -9
   -SIGKILL -KILL.
```

**EDIT**:
`kill -l` (the `bash` built-in command) lists the following signal names and numeric values on my system:

```
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL       5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT      7) SIGBUS       8) SIGFPE       9) SIGKILL     10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGUSR2     13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM
16) SIGSTKFLT   17) SIGCHLD     18) SIGCONT     19) SIGSTOP     20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGURG      24) SIGXCPU     25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGIO       30) SIGPWR
31) SIGSYS      34) SIGRTMIN    35) SIGRTMIN+1  36) SIGRTMIN+2  37) SIGRTMIN+3
38) SIGRTMIN+4  39) SIGRTMIN+5  40) SIGRTMIN+6  41) SIGRTMIN+7  42) SIGRTMIN+8
43) SIGRTMIN+9  44) SIGRTMIN+10 45) SIGRTMIN+11 46) SIGRTMIN+12 47) SIGRTMIN+13
48) SIGRTMIN+14 49) SIGRTMIN+15 50) SIGRTMAX-14 51) SIGRTMAX-13 52) SIGRTMAX-12
53) SIGRTMAX-11 54) SIGRTMAX-10 55) SIGRTMAX-9  56) SIGRTMAX-8  57) SIGRTMAX-7
58) SIGRTMAX-6  59) SIGRTMAX-5  60) SIGRTMAX-4  61) SIGRTMAX-3  62) SIGRTMAX-2
63) SIGRTMAX-1  64) SIGRTMAX
```

Comment: On Debian `kill -l` lists the numerical values too. What is your OS?

Comment: interesting, I'm running Ubuntu (which is Debian based as far as I know). On the other hand, I just noticed that `man kill` list numeric values for *some* of the signals.

Comment: Well, `kill` is in `procps`, which is version `1:3.2.8-9` in Debian squeeze. And yes, Ubuntu is basically Debian. So I wonder why `kill -l` doesn't return the same thing.

Comment: it turns out that I was running `zsh`'s builtin `kill` command, not `/bin/kill` (which actually lists the numeric values as you say)

Comment: @Andre: Wow, `zsh` has a `kill` command? Why? How does it differ from the regular `kill`? Does that mean that if someone in `zsh` uses `kill` he is using a different command? I think it merits mention in your answer itself, if only to clarify why you are using `/bin/kill` rather than just kill. It's strictly not part of the answer, but an interesting titbit none the less.

Comment: @Faheem, yes `zsh` has a builtin kill command. Looking through the corresponding section of `man zshbuiltins` it's however not clear how it differs from the procps `kill` command. Accidentally, I noticed that I can do `sleep 1000 &` and then `kill %sleep` which kills the sleep command I started (it kills the most recent one if there are multiple). `/bin/kill %sleep` does not work on the other hand.

By the way, `bash` seems to have a builtin kill command as well, it just is not reported by `which kill` (one has to do `type kill` to reveal this).

Comment: @Andre: Huh, weird. `bash` has a `kill` command? It doesn't seem to be invoked by default, so how to invoke it?

Comment: you can always do `builtin kill` to ensure that the built-in command is executed. But I bet that you were running the built-in `kill -l` when you got the numeric values of the signals. Contrary to what I posted before,  `/bin/kill -l` only gives me names, not numbers (and I didn't know that `bash` has a built-in `kill` command as well).

Comment: @Andre: You're right, it looks like `kill` actually does invoke the builtin, because I see that `kill -l` and '/bin/kill -l` give different outputs as you say. So `which` is not telling me what is actually executed. I think some dicussion of this point would be appropriate in this context, but we really need a shell expert to tell us what the point of these builtins is.

Comment: @Faheem, I think it's because the built-in commands have access to more information, such as the history of started commands, which `/bin/kill` seems not to have. For example, `kill %1` works for the built-in command but not with `/bin/kill` (although one could argue that in principle the shell could expand `%1` to the corresponding process id).

Comment: @FaheemMitha There are two reasons why shells need a `kill` built-in. It allows the `kill` command to accept job numbers or names (e.g. `kill %1`). And it allows `kill` to be used even if some process count limit has been reached.

Comment: @Andre, @Gilles: Ok, I see. You mean if a new `kill` process cannot be generated because the maximum number of processes has been reached, the builtin `kill` will still work? Not clear on the other reason though. I usually use process ids with `kill`. Why doesn't /bin/kill work with a process id? Any link for this?

Comment: @Faheem, you can always use 'absolute' process numbers with `/bin/kill` but not things like `%1` (which refers to the  first job in the list of backgrounded jobs known to the shell)

Answer (score 0):

`man signal`

Will show you the mapping between signal numbers and signal names.